# Django heavy database query and data processing

Tags: python, ajax, django, optimization, celery

I have an function that does heavy database queries across a number of objects:

```
def some_func(user):
    group1 = user.manytomanyfield1.all()
    allinstances = []
    for item in group1:
        allinstances += group1.manytomanyfield2.all()
```

then i have a list 'allinstances' which is composite of objects. I need then to check whether the created 'allinstances' list has objects that have attribute 'name' which is same across some amount of objects in 'allinstances' list and remove the duplicates:

```
    names = []
    doubleList = []
    for number, object1 in enumerate(allinstances):
        if object1.name not in names:
            names.append(object1.name)
        else:
            doubleList.append(number)
    doubleList.reverse()
    for item in doubleList:
    allinstances.pop(item)
return allinstances
```

When the size of allinstances is small the function executes very quick. But my app scope is such that it most commonly would work with amounts of several tens of thousands and possibly couple hundred thousands of 'object1's so 'allinstances' list would be huge and so the function execution would take a quiet a long time. Currently with ~25000 'object1's in 'allinstances' the function execution takes 10 seconds. This is unaffordable for me as the returned list further is put into Paginator and the Listview with object1's details is constructed from the result and so the user has to wait while the function executes.

I see the following options for reducing this bottleneck:
1. Optimize the function execution speed
2. Change my view to work with AJAX and reroute the function execution to asynchronous task queue like Celery. The AJAX on the page then inquires for result in some intervals and when the task is completed adds the result on the page.

Are there any best practices in such situation?
Maybe there is any other much more viable solution?
Any code improvement suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

One very quick optimization would be to make `names` a set, since list lookup is linear (O(n)) whereas set lookup is constant (O(1)):

```
names = set()
doubleList = []
for number, object1 in enumerate(allinstances):
    if object1.name not in names:
        names.add(object1.name)
```

Comment: amazingly for ~25k objects it really turns everything upside down changing execution time from 9-10 seconds to ~650ms

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of your performance issues are coming from Django having to run ~25000 queries happening when you have a lot of records.

[prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) is what I would use here.

The first section of your code would look like the following:

```
def some_func(user):
    group1 = user.manytomanyfield1.all().prefetch_related('manytomanyfield2')
    allinstances = []
    for item in group1:
         allinstances += item.manytomanyfield2.all()
```

Comment: My database is organised in hierarchical way such that there is not intersections between actual `object1` instances in a `manytomanyfield2` relationship. This means that instances in `group1` would return list of objects by running `item.manytomanyfield2.all()` which have no intersections at all. The one and only intersection is in the `.name` atrribute (which is a `CharField`)of `allinstances` instance list.